# FileStreamResult Re-route or Update Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a a method as:

```
public FileStreamResult CreateReport(int Id)
{
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
  tw.WriteLine(Id.ToString());
  tw.Flush();
  memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "text") { FileDownloadName = "Report.TXT"};
}
```

The method is trigger from a table, i would like to update the table after the file is download. Any way to re-direct to another action after the file has been download? or to update the model associate with the View?